# HTML String Line Break in Javascript

Tags: javascript, indentation

I am trying to output html with jQuery.

```
$('body').append('
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
');
```

I want to indent the code in this way for higher readability. 
It works for php but not in JS, any ideas? I use notepad++ as editor.

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working in JS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').append('\n\
<div>\n\
  <div>\n\
    <div></div>\n\
  </div>\n\
</div>\n\
');
```

- The `\n` is to insert a newline character in your string (so it’ll get outputted in your body element)
- The final `\` is Javascript's line continuation character, so you can keep your JS code indented without having to add `+ ''` everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using a templating system for that. No matter how much indentation you use, if you mix to much HTML and Javascript you will end-up will spaghetti code.

### HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

### Javascript

```
$('body').append($('#my-template').html());
```

If you need more control over your template rendering, you need to use a library. I recommend [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), its not the best templating engine for javascript, but it's very lightweight and comes with a great set of helper functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('body').append('\
<div>\
  <div>\
    <div>foo</div>\
  </div>\
</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Javascript string literals?  "\n" is a newline, and "\t" is a tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indent, I suggest using the concatenation operator "+" whenever you want to add a new line in your code:

```
$('body').append(
'<div>' +
  '<div>' +
    '<div></div>' +
  '</div>' +
'</div>'
);
```